# Spark executors with different amounts of memory on Mesos

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

Is it possible to have executors with different amounts of memory on a Mesos cluster? Or am I bounded by the machine with the least memory? (Assuming I want to use all available cpus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short anwer:** No.

Unfortunately, *Spark Mesos* and *YARN* only allow giving as much resources (cores, memory, etc.) per machine as your *worst* machine has ([discussion](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/heterogeneous-cluster-hardware-td11567.html)). Ideally, the cluster should be homogeneous in order to take full advantage of its resources.

However, there might exist a workaround for your problem. According to the linked source above, *Spark* standalone allows creating multiple workers on some machines. You might modify your worker configuration to be appropriate for the *worst* machine, and start multiple workers on these.

For example, given two computers with 4G and 20G memory respectively, you could create 5 workers on the latter, each with a configuration to use just 4G of memory, as limited per the first machine.